# macro VBA nunca abre mi fichero

Tags: vba

El codigo es el siguiente:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
Dim exec As String


exec = "powershell.exe (New-Object System.Net.WebClient)."
exec = "DownloadFile('https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/w32/putty.exe','%temp%/putty.exe');Start-Process"
exec = " '%temp%/putty.exe'"
End Sub
```

Se ejecuta bien pero nunca abre o descarga el fichero con la macro.

Answer (score 1):

Dado lo escueto de la consulta, he de suponer cosas: Estás trabajando en Excel, con VBA, y deseas que la macro diseñada realice determinadas acciones externas a la aplicación. En tu propuesta sólo estás asignando valores a una variable de tipo string; no se producen errores, pero con ese código nunca obtendrás el resultado buscado.

El medio para realizar ese tipo de acciones es la función SHELL. Shell espera dos argumentos:
* la orden o comando que se ha de ejecutar, entre comillas ("orden") y
* la forma en que Windows ha de mostrar la orden o aplicación

Esta función produce un valor con el identificador de la aplicación, si ha podido lanzarla, o "0" si no ha obtenido el éxito buscado.

Supón que deseas arrancar el block de notas:

```
DIM PID as variant
PID = Shell("notepad", vbNormalFocus)
```

Se iniciará el notepad, con posición y tamaño acordes con el uso más reciente, y se le pasa el foco del sistema para poderla emplear.
Puedes abrir, sobre la marcha, un cierto archivo:

```
PID = Shell("notepad ejercicio.txt", vbNormalFocus)
```

o, si el nombre contiene espacios:

```
PID = Shell("notepad ""nombre archivo.txt""", vbNormalFocus)
```

A la hora de cerrar la aplicación:

```
PID = Shell ("TaskKill /F /PID " & PID, vbHide)
```

Puedes ejecutar comandos del sistema (dir, copy, del, etc.) mediante:

```
PID = Shell("cmd /k dir")
```

La "/k" es para que la ventana de línea de comandos no se cierre.

Espero haberte ayudado.